# How to refetch images in a single page app?

Tags: javascript, html, caching, browser, single-page-application

I've done a lot of research and tried a lot of stuff to fix my problem but either I'm doing something wrong or I just don't know what to do.

I have this JS single page app that displays image thumbnails. I set the images response header to use etags because each thumbnail might change over time.

What happens is this:
1. I load the page and see that there's a GET call made to retrieve the thumbnail with these response headers (etag is set, cache-control with no-cache, expire date is set one day in the past):

```
date: Wed, 25 Mar 2015 13:24:56 GMT
cache-control: private, no-cache, max-age=0
expires: Tue Mar 24 2015 09:24:56 GMT-0400 (EDT)
etag: 1427215131000
```

2. I go to another section of the page (thumbnail are not displayed on the page).
3. I come back to the thumbnails view and I see the thumbnail images back but not refetch made (**no GET call made to retrieve the thumbnail**).

I need to have this GET call being made to verify whether the image has changed on the server (based on the etag). Btw, I also turned off caching in the browser and I still don't see any GET calls.

Anyone knows how to fix this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used socket.io. Whenever an image is changed on the back-end, and update message is sent through socket.io, informing the front-end that a particular image has changed and will need to be refetched.

The front-end will make sure that next call to this image will add a timestamp to the end of the call to make a refetch call to the server.

Ex.:

1. User comes to the page, image URL is `http://www.example.com/images/logo.png`.
2. User navigates on the site, image URL is still `http://www.example.com/images/logo.png`.
3. Image changes on the back-end: event is sent to front-end.
4. User navigates through the single web app and logo image has to be displayed again. Image URL has been changed to `http://www.example.com/images/logo.png?_=1427980814941`.
5. User navigates on the site, image URL is yet still now `http://www.example.com/images/logo.png?_=1427980814941`.
6. Should there be another change on the back-end, we'd get back to step 3.